# Nonlinear regression in R shows error

Tags: r, nonlinear-optimization

I am using the R function `nlsLM` from the package `minpack.LM`  and I have the following error.

I generate my own signal with noise, so I know all parameters, which I'am trying to find doing regression analysis using the same function, I've used to generate signal.

The problem is, that `nlsLM` function runs fine, and it even could find right parameters values, but at last, when it finds them, error appear like this:

It.   23, RSS =    14.4698, Par. =    42.6727    0.78112          1    65.2211    15.6065          1

It.   24, RSS =    14.4698, Par. =     42.671   0.781102          1    65.2212    15.6069          1

**Error in stats:::nlsModel(formula, mf, start, wts) : 
  singular gradient matrix at initial parameter estimates**

And I do not know what to do.
Please explain what it could be, and how I could solve it!

Additional information:

```
#This is how i generate my signal (it is convolution of gaussian with exp(-kt)

set.seed(100)

Yexp=sim_str_exp(error=10)

time=Yexp[[1]]

y=Yexp[[2]]

dataset_nls=data.frame(time,y)

start=c(tau1=.5,beta1=.5,exp_A1=.5,gaus_pos=.5,gaus_width=.5,gaus_A=0.5)

lower=c(tau1=0.01,beta1=0.01,exp_A1=0.01,gaus_pos=0.01,gaus_width=0.01,gaus_A=0.01)

upper=c(tau1=100,beta1=1,exp_A1=1,gaus_pos=100,gaus_width=850,gaus_A=1)

#here i do fitting

FIT=nlsLM(y ~ str_exp_model(time,tau1,beta1,exp_A1,gaus_pos,gaus_width,gaus_A),data=dataset_nls,start=start,lower=lower,upper=upper,trace=TRUE,algorithm="LM",na.action=na.pass,control=nls.lm.control(maxiter=200,nprint=1))

#Model_function

str_exp_model<-function(time, tau1,beta1,exp_A1,gaus_pos,gaus_width,gaus_A){
F_gen_V<-vector(length=length(time))

F_gaus_V=vector(length=length(time))
F_exp_V=vector(length=length(time))
for (i in 1:length(time)) {
F_gaus_V[i]=gaus_A*exp(-2.77*((i-gaus_pos)/gaus_width)^2)
F_exp_V[i]=exp_A1*exp(-1*(i/tau1)^beta1)
}

convolve(F_gaus_V, F_exp_V,FALSE)
}
```

## function for signal generation

```
sim_str_exp<- function(num_points=512,time_scale=512,tau1=45,beta1=.80,exp_A1=1,gaus_pos=65,
```

gaus_width=15, gaus_A=1,Y0=0, error=2.0, show_graph=TRUE, norm="False"){

```
F_gen_V<-vector(length=num_points)
time_gen_V<-vector(length=num_points)
F_gaus_V=vector(length=num_points)
F_exp_V=vector(length=num_points)
ts=time_scale/num_points
sigma=vector(length=num_points)


for (i in 1:num_points) {
F_gaus_V[i]=gaus_A*exp(-2.77*((i*ts-gaus_pos)/gaus_width)^2)
F_exp_V[i]=exp_A1*exp(-1*(i*ts/tau1)^beta1)
time_gen_V[i]=i*ts
}

F_gen_V<-(convolve(F_gaus_V, F_exp_V,FALSE))+Y0

if(norm==TRUE){
F_gen_V=F_gen_V/max(F_gen_V)}
else{;}

error_V=runif(512,-1*error, error)

for(i in 1:num_points){
F_gen_V[i]=error_V[i]/100*F_gen_V[i]+F_gen_V[i]
sigma[i]=(error_V[i]/100*F_gen_V[i])
}

RETURN=list(time=time_gen_V,y=F_gen_V,sigma=sigma)

if (show_graph==TRUE){
plot(RETURN[[1]],RETURN[[2]], type="l", main="Generated signal with noise",xlab="time,        pixel",ylab="Intensity");}
else {;}

return(RETURN)

}
```

Comment: maybe it failed to converge?

Comment: can you show us `sim_str_exp` ?  I assume it's just `str_exp_model` + noise ...

Comment: Now, @BenBolker , you know what they say about "assume"  :-(

Comment: OK, I should have said "I'm guessing ..."

Answer (score 2):

You haven't shown us `sim_str_exp`, so this example isn't fully reproducible, but I'm going to take a guess here.  You say "I generate my own signal with noise", but you use `Yexp=sim_str_exp(error=0)` to generate the data, so it looks like you're not in fact adding any noise.  (Also, your reported RSS at the last step is `1.37e-28` ...)

My guess is that you're running into a problem documented in `?nls`, which is that `nls()` doesn't work well when there is zero noise.  This is *not* documented in `?nlsLM`, but I wouldn't be surprised if it held there too.

For convenience, here is the section I'm referring to from `?nls`:

> *Do not use ‘nls’ on artificial "zero-residual" data.*
>
> ```
>  The ‘nls’ function uses a relative-offset convergence criterion
>  that compares the numerical imprecision at the current parameter
>  estimates to the residual sum-of-squares.  This performs well on
>  data of the form
>
>                         y = f(x, theta) + eps                       
>
>  (with ‘var(eps) > 0’).  It fails to indicate convergence on data
>  of the form
>
>                            y = f(x, theta)                          
>
>  because the criterion amounts to comparing two components of the
>  round-off error.  If you wish to test ‘nls’ on artificial data
>  please add a noise component, as shown in the example below.
> ```

If my hypothesis is correct then you should be able to get a fit without errors if you set the noise amplitude greater than zero.

Comment: `nlsLM` does much better with zero noise data than `nls`: http://www.r-bloggers.com/a-better-nls/

Comment: OK, but maybe still an issue in this particular case?

Comment: I cannot exclude the possibility. :)

Comment: I' ve edited my question. I modelled data with error, it gives the same thing. Sorry for crappy question at begginng. Hope You could help me with this problem